# Invocar Service a partir de um then() resultante de outro service

Tags: angularjs

A situação é a seguinte, a partir do `controller equipecontrol`, estou percorrendo um `forEach`, no interior de um `then()`, que possui um resultado obtido anteriormente através da execução da função `getEscalacao()`, que está definida no service `EquipeService`, conforme consta no código abaixo.

```
example.controller('equipecontrol', ['EquipeService','PessoasService','$scope','$q', function(EquipeService,PessoasService,$scope,$q) {
    Parse.initialize('APPLICATION_ID', 'JAVASCRIPT_KEY'); 
    Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com';

    EquipeService.getEscalacao().then(function (escalacao) {
        var idjogador = '';

        angular.forEach(escalacao, function (atuacao) {
            idjogador = atuacao.attributes['jogador'].id; //id do jogador
            gtStorageJogador = PessoasService.getPessoasStorage(idjogador); //<-- aqui invoco a função do outro service

            console.log(gtStorageJogador) //<-- este console não apresentada nada
        })
    })
}]);
```

Observe no código acima que obtenho o `idjogador` na iteração atual, classe `Escalacao`, e tento pesquisá-lo na classe `PeopleObject` invocando a função `getPessoasStorage()` que está definida em outro `service` de nome `PessoasService`, observe também que passo `idjogador` como parâmetro. Segue o código do `service PessoasService`:

```
example.service('PessoasService', [function () {
    var jogadorDadosStorage = {};

    return {
        getPessoasStorage: function (params) {
            var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("PeopleObject");
            var PeopleQuery = new Parse.Query(PeopleObject);

            //console.log(params)
            if(params !== undefined) {
                PeopleQuery.equalTo('objectId',params);
            }

            PeopleQuery.find({   
                success: function(pessoas) {
                    for (var i = pessoas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        objpessoas = pessoas[i];

                        idpessoa   = objpessoas.id
                        nomepessoa = objpessoas.get('username');
                        posorigem  = objpessoas.attributes.posicaooriginal.id;

                        emailpes   = objpessoas.get('email');
                        senhapes   = objpessoas.get('senha');   
                        dtalter    = objpessoas.get('updatedAt');
                        dtcreate   = objpessoas.get('createdAt');

                        jogadorDadosStorage = { 
                            'id'      : idpessoa,
                            'nome'    : nomepessoa,
                            'posorig' : posorigem,
                            'email'   : emailpes,
                            'senha'   : senhapes,
                            'dtalt'   : dtalter,
                            'dtcria'  : dtcreate
                        }
                    }                
                }, error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Error da Query PeopleObject: " + error.code + " " + error.message)
                    var objSrv = {};
                }
            })

            return jogadorDadosStorage;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Ainda não sei o porquê desta lógica não estar funcionando. Coloquei um `console.log(gtStorageJogador)` mas ele não apresenta resultados, é como se a função `getPessoasStorage` não estivesse sendo executada neste momento, acho que pode ser um problema associado a questão de assincronia.

Neste trecho do programa, ou seja, ao percorrer o `forEach` para cada item da classe `Escalacao`, eu preciso de uma função que possa me trazer da classe `PeopleObject` o nome correspondente ao `idjogador` posicionado neste instante na classe `Escalacao`, pois minha intenção no final de tudo isso é preencher um objeto contendo dados de várias classes, para poder exibir em uma *view*.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Como você está utilizando um serviço do tipo `service` você deve retornar as funções com a declaração `this` para que sejam acessadas, deste modo:

```
example.service('PessoasService', [function () {
    var jogadorDadosStorage = {};

    this.getPessoasStorage: function (params) {
        // Sua função aqui

        return jogadorDadosStorage;
    }
}]);
```

O modo como você declarou seria para uso de um serviço do tipo `factory`. Mas tente com a alteração que recomendei e veja se funciona.

Comment: Olá CelsomTrindade, boa noite! obrigado pela sua atenção! após implementar o this. o sistema apresentou o seguinte: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "

Comment: Percebi agora o seguinte, a função getPessoasStorage está sendo executada, mas só após a conclusão do "angular.forEach(escalacao, function (atuacao)". Como eu posso resolver isso?, ou seja,  fazer com que  getPessoasStorage seja executada ao passo que estou percorrendo cada item da escalacao ?